# Put Ads in an React SPA with Infinite Scroll

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ads, infinite-scroll

I have a React Single Page Web App which looks like a very simplified version of hotel/flight search page. User select tags as a filter and filtered results are displayed in an infinite scroll fashion. Whenever a filter is selected or user scrolls to the bottom, SPA fetches data from my backend server, and the React App's states is changed, thus updating the display. My React static page is also served from my backend.

I am considering adding one advertisement in between every 10 results or so.

However, my main concern is that since I only have one single HTML file (because everything is handled by React), the way how many times ads are shown may be counted incorrectly. Or even worse my website may not be eligible to display ads.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?
Thank you very much!